# What's the error in this API agent on frontend side?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I was following the course when I ran into an error that the instructor didn't. I spent too much time on trying to figure out what was wrong, but unfortunately without success.

I'm trying to make a generic API agent using Axios.

The error is following:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
on line

> 23 | const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;

The code for the agent is:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { Activity } from '../models/Activity';

const sleep = (delay: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay)
    })
}


axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://localhost:44333/api';

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    sleep(1000).then(() => {
        return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("err", error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    })
})

const responseBody = <T> (response: AxiosResponse<T>) => response.data;

const requests = {
    get: <T> (url: string) => axios.get<T>(url).then(responseBody),
    post: <T> (url: string, body: {}) => axios.post<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put: <T> (url: string, body: {}) => axios.put<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
    delete: <T> (url: string) => axios.delete<T>(url).then(responseBody)
}

const Activities = {
    list: () => requests.get<Activity[]>('/Activities')
}

const agent = {
    Activities
}

export default agent;
```

Update:
I found out where the issue was and replaced the corresponding part of code with this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(async response => {
    try {
        await sleep(1000);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return await Promise.reject(error);
    }
})
```

But still, I don't know why this solved the issue. I would appreciate the explanation

Comment: You didn't originally return a promise from use function, that's the difference.

Comment: @EstusFlask would you mind explaining how? I thought I'm returning response because of sleep(1000).then(() => {
        return response;
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it, the solution is following code:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    **return** sleep(1000).then(() => {
        return response;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("err", error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    })
})
```

So I missed here **return** keyword before sleep function.
This could also be the solution:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(async response => {
    try {
        await sleep(1000);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return await Promise.reject(error);
    }
})
```

Comment: Also there's already a promise, can be `throw error` instead of Promise.reject